# Linear Algebra: Linear Recurrences with Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, recurrence-relations, recursion

Let $P= \mathbb{C}[x] $ be the vector space of polynomials with complex coefficents. 
We define the following linear recurrence
$p_{0}(x)=1$, 
$p_{1}(x)=x$,  $p_{n}(x)=p_{n-1}(x)-p_{n-2}(x)$  for $n \geq 2$

How do I formulate this in the form $y_{n}=Ay_{n-1}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear from the definition of $\bigl(p_n(x)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}_+):\deg p_n(x)\leqslant1.$$So, let us work in the space $\mathbb{C}_1[x]$ of all polynomials $p(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $\deg p(x)\leqslant1$. If such a linear map $A$ existes, then $A(1)=x$ and $A(x)=-1+x$. But, since $\{1,x\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}_1[x]$, there is one and only one such map: $A(a+bx)=ax+b(-1+x)=-b+(a+b)x$. Does it work? You can see that $A(-1+x)=-1$. Also, $A(-1)=-x$, $A(-x)=1$, and $A(1)=x$ (by definition), and we're back to the first polynomial. And you can easily see that your sequence is also$$1,x,-1+x,-1,-x,1,\ldots$$

Comment: I understand more now, but I still dont see how to construct the matrix A.

Comment: @bullbo $A$ is *not* a matrix; it's a linear map. Since $A(1)=x$ and since $A(x)=-1+x$, then, for any $a,b\in\mathbb R$\begin{align}A(a+bx)&=aA(1)+bA(x)\\&=ax+b(-1+x)\\&=-b+(a+b)x.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Look at the first few terms. $p_2(x)=x-1;p_3(x)=-1;p_4(x)=-x;p_5(x)=-x+1;p_6(x)=1;p_7(x)=x$

Do you see some relation?